# Problems with AnnotationView and Close button

Tags: iphone, annotations, popup, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I need help with MKMapView .In map i show pictures after click on picture shows popUp wih biggest picture and title (AnnotationView) but i cannot added any buttons ... they just dont work.Then i try this

```
cancelButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
[cancelButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"map_dialog_cancel.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cancelButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0 , 0.0, 25.0, 25.0 )];
[cancelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.leftCalloutAccessoryView = cancelButton;
self.canShowCallout = YES;
```

but now start show    standart popup  with button  above my custom popup...How i can put close button in my popup?

Comment: When the system allows you, put your solution here as an answer. In due time you can accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok problems resolved all u need in your AnnotationView class added

```
 -(UIView*)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{

    [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    if (point.x > buttonFrame.origin.x &&  point.y > buttonFrame.origin.y   && point.x <      buttonFrame.origin.x +buttonFrame.size.width && point.y < buttonFrame.origin.y +buttonFrame.size.height) 
{
    NSLog(@"handlePinButtonTap: ");
   [delegate closePopUpPressed:self];

}
 return nil;
}
```

Who have better solution please write here